Eclipse / Git Integration - unable to change username/password for a repo under Git Repositories -> Remote -> Origin
Referring to the attached screenshot, where does Eclipse get this username? Also, how can I change it? I'm asking it since this dialog doesn't persist my changes. I understand I'm using HTTPS in Eclipse, but I can push/pull from Windows terminal just fine.


What's the output when you run git remote -v inside your local clone's directory?

@nitind - It's the same as what's in the URI. My confusion is about the value of User under the Authentication section. Also, this dialog doesn't persist my changes.
